# What's wrong with this title?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions, policy

> [What's wrong with Black Widow?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61196/41570)

Seriously, what's wrong with this title?

See [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/61196/revisions) revision history. People are making trivial changes to the title. While the third revision to the title claims to get it off the [Hot Network Questions](http://stackexchange.com/), the fifth just has "edited title" comment.

I believe there are [algorithms/formulas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/217907) in place to calculate ["arbitrary hotness points"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/217907). Still people are making changes and the fifth change is just trivial.

Is there anyway I can get my question locked for making changes to the title? Or can a Mod or a user with such privileges can get it locked for me?

**Edit:** I totally agree with you @Rathony. However, what I still believe is, **question titles are not supposed to have all the information in them**. There is a reason for question body and tags to exist, or so I believed so far.

My question title had enough information it should have. It contained "Black Widow" and it also informed the user that something was wrong with her. The remaining information was supplied by tags and question body. So I see it as legitimate in every way possible.

If we are obliged to be too much informative in the title itself, then I would suggest the title to read like below.

> What medical procedure was performed (forcibly or not), on Black Widow, by her trainers, as the "Last Test", in the "Red Room" facility, in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, which technically prevented her from getting pregnant, so that it does not get in her way to complete a mission?

The current title as locked by a mod doesn't reflect my feelings when I thought of the question in my mind. I wouldn't want to use certain words in a question title and unfortunately I would have to [bear with them](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/is-it-bear-or-bare-with-me).

I thank the Mod to lock the question on my request, however I am not happy with the change; reverting back to revision three. I have requested the Mod to restore my original title, but I believe it is being ignored.

Comment: Thunderforge's reason is "Making the title more explicit since this is a Hot Network Question. The original could be interpreted in too many ways". Seems quite clear to me, he just tried to make it more clear to represent the main question and removed vagueness. Cross argument can me made that his title is bit spoiler-full.

Comment: He didn't change the title to get it *off* the HNQ list. Where do you take that from? He changed it *because* it was an HNQ and thus should show the question (and this way our site) from its best and clearest side. And your title is frankly too broad and doesn't say *anything* about the question at all. But granted, I have indeed locked it for you now.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson  _Making the title more explicit since this is a Hot Network Question._ was the edit comment hence the conclusion. Agree, that might be wrong conclusion. Thank you for locking the question for me, however, I would request you to restore the original title. Because, I don't think it's that broad. Besides titles are titles, they are not required to have the whole question content in them, I believe.

Comment: I wonder, what could be the possible reason for down vote? As I don't see any comment mentioning it.

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi Unlike the main board, downvotes on Meta usually mean "I don't agree with your post." It's not about helpfulness or research effort. Also, you need to note that users are not obligated to leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: Look at [these](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/94699/i-love-you-i-love-you-i-love-you) [titles](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/94832/yes-of-course-im-an-adult) from codegolf. I am just saying.... ;)

Comment: Examples don't make cases, neither is this site [codegolf.se].

Comment: The fifth change was not trivial. It was to remove the inherent sexism in your preferred title, after you revert the better pregnant title. You didn't want pregnant in the title, fine, but saying something is wrong with her is as sexist as the movie saying it.

Comment: Also I flagged it for lock based on the edit war that was approaching.

Comment: There wasn't the slightest hint of sexism at play here. I think we should all calm down and reconsider our judgment of other people's intentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once had the same feeling when other users tried to edit a post, which seemed trivial. But I asked myself, "What's wrong with the edited post?" and moved on.

I think you should ask yourself "What's wrong with What was done to prevent Black Widow from getting pregnant?" I don't see any particular problem with the edited title.

Nothing is wrong with either your title or edited one. Let's move on.

**Edit**: Regarding how much information should a title contain in comparison with a question body, there is no hard-and-fast rule. But, the rules of thumb for a title should be

(1) it should be as concise as possible

(2) it should have enough information for a reader to identify the core issue

(3) it should help current and future readers to search it more easily.

The above points are as subjective as they get. I think arguing about this issue would be neither constructive nor helpful because there is no clear and objective answer.

Comment: Added some more arguments in favor of my original title in the _question body_.  I hope they don't make me add something to this very question's title, as it is very similar. :)

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi I edited my answer. Let's move on.

Comment: Apparently I don't have any other choice, have I? :(

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi Yes, that's what I felt when it happened to me. You either fight with moderators or move on. Which will be wiser? Well, I **did fight** a few times and you can't beat them.

Comment: Also - the title should not contain any spoilers (if possible).